# Are there standard versions of `sed` on which `-E` is unsupported?

Tags: sed, posix, gnu, bsd

On BSD sed, `-E` is the "extended regex" flag.  On GNU sed, the documentation states that `-r` is the extended regex flag, but the `-E` switch works as well (though undocumented in my research).

I recall reading somewhere that `-E` will be specified in the next edition of POSIX specifications, but I can't find where I read that.

(Is that true?  Is there an authoritative reference for that, or a user here who *is* an authority?)

**Just how portable *is* the `-E` switch for `sed`?**

Are there standard (i.e. POSIX compliant) versions of `sed` on which `-E` is unsupported?  (Which ones?)

Why is the `-E` flag not documented for GNU sed?

Comment: I can't explain why they did it, but the source for GNU sed includes the comment about processing `-E`: `/* Undocumented, for compatibility with BSD sed.  */` and handles it exactly the same as `-r`

Comment: @EricRenouf, Nice find; can you provide a link also?  :)

Comment: As it happens, I was luck with the version of source I was looking at, but I'll do you one better now.  [Here's the commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/commit/sed/sed.c?id=8b65e07904384b529a464c89f3739d2e7e4d5135) where the comment I cited was removed, and it includes there the log message "Modify documentation to note sed "-E" option, now in POSIX, for EREs.", which was made in 2013-10-16, so I'm surprised it hasn't made it into the docs or similar, though my Cent OS 7 box has a version from 2012 still

Comment: That said, I can't find the reference to it in the latest (I think) POSIX doc for sed

Comment: @EricRenouf, That commit (and the [page linked from it](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528)) answers nearly every part of my question.  Could you please make your comment an answer?  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GNU first added undocumented support for `-E` just to be compatible with BSD syntax, and the source included the comment

> /* Undocumented, for compatibility with BSD sed.  */

But in 2013 that was removed in [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/commit/sed/sed.c?id=8b65e07904384b529a464c89f3739d2e7e4d5135) with the log message

> Modify documentation to note sed "-E" option, now in POSIX, for EREs.

and the commit references a defect tracker for POSIX at [this page](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528) that marks as accepted adding the `-E` flag to the `sed` arguments

It doesn't seem to have made it into the [latest POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) ([sed specific part](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)) though, but I guess it's coming.

Comment: Of course it is also missing from older distros.  I've just discovered that the Sed included in RHEL 5 doesn't support `-E`, though it *does* support `-r`.  (This might seem obvious for environments that include old systems, but *I* had forgotten to check.)

Comment: @Wildcard I guess that makes sense.  Since they added the `-E` to be compatible with other flags, there had to be a time that predated that addition

Comment: `-E` still hasn't arrived in POSIX.  The [Austin Group Issue](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528) has it tagged for POSIX Issue 8. [POSIX drafts are available (with effort)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607346/143394)

Answer (score 6):

The place to look is at systems which are certified:

- [AIX](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/sed.htm), no
- [HPUX](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/sed.1.html), no
- [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/sed-1.html#scrolltoc), no

[OSX](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) has it, though whether it's BSD- or GNU-first was not part of the question.

Comment: Given the comment I found in the GNU source, I think it's safe to assume BSD did it first

Comment: Seems odd that this isn't the accepted answer...