# Delete string between two regex patterns

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file with following contents

```
..\..\src\modules\core\abc\abc.cpp
..\..\src\modules\core\something\xyz\xyz.cpp
..\..\src\other_modules\new_core\something\pqr\pqr.cpp
..\..\src\other_modules\new_core\something\pqr\abc.cpp
```

The result I am expecting is

```
..\..\src\abc\abc.cpp
..\..\src\xyz\xyz.cpp
..\..\src\pqr\pqr.cpp
..\..\src\pqr\abc.cpp
```

How can I achieve this using sed?

I am unable to write an regular expression to capture two groups at the same time.

1. initial group (....\src) - this will be same in all the lines
2. variable group (abc\abc.cpp) or (xyz\xyz.cpp) or (pqr\pqr.cpp) or (pqr\abc.cpp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With BSD `sed` or recent versions of GNU `sed` (for older versions, replace `-E` with `-r`):

```
sed -E 's#(.*\\src).*(\\[^\]+\\[^\]+$)#\1\2#' file.txt
```

- `#` is used as the delimiter for substitution (`s`) command of `sed`, to avoid ambiguity involving `\`s in the input
- `(.*\\src)` matches upto `src` from start, and put the match in captured group 1
- `(\\[^\]+\\[^\]+$)` matches the portion having two `\`s till end, and put in captured group 2, the `.*` preceding this matches everything in between the first and second captured groups
- In the replacement we have used the two captured groups

POSIX-ly:

```
sed 's#\(.*\\src\).*\(\\[^\]\+\\[^\]\+$\)#\1\2#' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
..\..\src\modules\core\abc\abc.cpp
..\..\src\modules\core\something\xyz\xyz.cpp
..\..\src\other_modules\new_core\something\pqr\pqr.cpp
..\..\src\other_modules\new_core\something\pqr\abc.cpp

% sed -E 's#(.*\\src).*(\\[^\]+\\[^\]+$)#\1\2#' file.txt
..\..\src\abc\abc.cpp
..\..\src\xyz\xyz.cpp
..\..\src\pqr\pqr.cpp
..\..\src\pqr\abc.cpp
```

Comment: could you let me know why did you use `sed -E`

Comment: @phoenix The `-E` option lets us to use ERE (Extended RegEx) patterns, otherwise we have to use BRE (Basic RegEx) patterns. In practice, we then need to escape the `()`s in the captured groups, `+` token, and also `{}`, `?` if present and used as Regex token, otherwise these will be treated literally. Without `-E`: `sed 's#\(.*\\src\).*\(\\[^\]\+\\[^\]\+$\)#\1\2#' file.txt`

Comment: @phoenix, not only that, but `\+` (as in above comment) is much less portable than using `-E` and `+`.  `-E` is [fairly standard](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/310446/135943).

Comment: can also use `sed -E 's#(.*\\src).*((\\[^\]+){2})$#\1\2#'` to avoid repeating regex pattern, can easily change number as well if requirement changes....

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with data

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 sasi   webApp  190 Oct  4 13:42 file.txt
```

Execute below command

```
[sasi@localhost temp]$ sed -E 's#(.*\\src).*(\\[^\]+\\[^\]+$)#\1\2#' file.txt
..\..\src\abc\abc.cpp
..\..\src\xyz\xyz.cpp
..\..\src\pqr\pqr.cpp
..\..\src\pqr\abc.cpp
[sasi@localhost temp]$
[sasi@localhost temp]$
[sasi@localhost temp]$
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you format your answer, also I see an error in the regular expression that you are suggesting

Comment: sed -E 's#(.\src).(\[^]+\[^]+$)#\1\2#' file.txt

Comment: run above command with file.txt

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: which OS using ? Bec i can get a result with same command ..

Comment: I am using cygwin in Windows OS.
The pattern you mentioned in your answer and in your comment are different. Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46276/discussion-between-phoenix-and-sasikaran).

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solutions:

With GNU `grep` and `paste`

`grep` extracts the two patterns `.*\\src` or `(\\[^\]+){2}$` and prints them on separate lines. The output is then combined using `paste`

```
$ grep -oE '.*\\src|(\\[^\]+){2}$' ip.txt | paste -d '' - -
..\..\src\abc\abc.cpp
..\..\src\xyz\xyz.cpp
..\..\src\pqr\pqr.cpp
..\..\src\pqr\abc.cpp
```

With `perl`

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*\\src\K.*(?=(\\[^\\]+){2}$)//' ip.txt 
..\..\src\abc\abc.cpp
..\..\src\xyz\xyz.cpp
..\..\src\pqr\pqr.cpp
..\..\src\pqr\abc.cpp
```

Here the text between the patterns `.*\\src` and `(\\[^\\]+){2}$` is deleted by making use of positive lookarounds

Comment: Thank you Sundeep, learnt grepping two patterns and also paste command. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why bash this with regex? Path munging doesn't require regular expressions; OS kernels don't use regexes to follow paths.

With Awk, we just use backslash as a separator and components become fields:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\\" } { print $1, $2, $3, $(NF-1), $NF }'
```