# View POSIX draft standards

Tags: sed, posix, standard

The GNU `sed` manpage says:

> The `-E` option switches to using extended regular expressions instead;        it
> has been supported for years by GNU sed, and is now included in POSIX.

However, [POSIX Issue 7 (2018) `sed` doesn't list `-E` as an option](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

Where can POSIX draft standards be viewed?

Answer (score 19):

Drafts are [only available to Austin Group members](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/docreg.html), but the information is publicly available in the Austin Group bug tracker: [`sed -E` is queued for issue 8](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528). (Joining the Austin Group only requires [signing up to the mailing list](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/lists.html).)

So the manpage is only slightly ahead of itself...

Answer (score 14):

Draft POSIX documents are being worked on by the The Austin Common Standards Revision Group, who [announce](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/):

> Jun 2020: The first draft of the 202x revision of the standard is now available.

The draft is relatively [tightly guarded](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/login.html):

> In order to download drafts from this web site, Austin Group members need to login using their individual web accounts and passwords.

> Permission is granted to Austin Group participants to download and reproduce these documents for the purposes of Austin Group standardization activities. Other entities or persons seeking permission to reproduce these documents, or to reproduce portions of the document for any purpose must contact the copyright owners for express written permission.

I was able to become a Austin Group member via [sign-up to the mailing list](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/lists.html).

I also saw a warning on the [Open Group Collaboration website](https://collaboration.opengroup.org/root/portal.php) that due to a bug, certain people needed to [resend the email address verification](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/common/ResendVerifyEmail.html), which I also did.

I checked that `The Austin Group` was coloured green when viewed via the [Open Group Portal](https://collaboration.opengroup.org/operational/portal.php)

I clicked the `accept` button on the [Austin Group Member Login](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/login.html) page, and logged in with the credentials created above.

I now have access to all 3785 pages of POSIX.1-202x Draft 1 Review Draft (June 2020).

The committee review for Draft 1 completed on August 25 2020 (from restricted link).

Issues with the Draft are available (publicly) via the [Austin Group Issue Tracker](https://austingroupbugs.net/view_all_bug_page.php). Filter by Project: `Issue 8 draft`.

Comment: Did you join with a private email address, or with an employer-provided address? Is your employer a member of the Open Group? (Trying to ascertain what the exact requirements are...)

Comment: @Stephen Kitt My business and private email address are one and the same (my own domain). I used the business email field though :)

Comment: Heh, so I imagine you’re not a member organisation of the Open Group then ;-). Interesting, so anyone can join!

Comment: Sorry, I missed the membership part of your question. I'm not a member, so for now anyone can join.